# Use link instead of text in Review Low Quality Posts "This answer should be an edit" reason

Tags: feature-request, comments, low-quality-posts, magic-links

So here's the reason:

> **This answer should be an edit to the question**
>
> Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

I'd suggest use a link instead of text about that `the edit link`, like our [[edit] magic link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/305595), but the link is to the question.

---

I wish we can use

> Please use the `[edit](/posts/<id>/)` link on your question to add additional information...

instead of

> Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information.

I think this would be more easy for new users to find the edit link.

Comment: A demo: Please use the [edit] link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: Wouldn't the magic edit link edit the answer, not the question they should be editing?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: Hmm...forgot that, never mind. We can do little change, wait me edit my question.

Comment: Nice. Maybe an `[edit-question]` magic link could be implemented to facilitate this.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: But do we have a `[edit-question]` magic link? :)

Comment: I don't think at the moment. That's why I suggested maybe one could be added.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: Actually I like it, so another meta post :P

Comment: _"I think this would be more easy for new users to find the edit link."_ I think it's a good way to ensure that they never do, since they now won't ever have to. #mollycoddling 101

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Ah, because someone asked me where's the edit link. So I think this would be little helpful for them.

Comment: Meta meta feature request for the [edit-question] magic-link: [Can we have an “edit question” magic link for answer comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264067/can-we-have-an-edit-question-magic-link-for-answer-comments)

Comment: @TinyGiant: Wow, cool :D

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think that argument has been made every time the use of the edit magic link has been discussed... and I still disagree. In practice, I can tell a user how to find the edit link three times and still end up using the magic link in a comment. This is especially prevalent with non-native English speakers.

Comment: @TinyGiant: I never understood how the non-native English argument was related. It's a lack of looking, not a lack of understanding.

Comment: @Lightness .... no, I'm pretty sure it can be a lack of understanding as well.

Comment: @TinyGiant: If they understand a link labelled "edit", they understand a link labelled "edit".

Comment: @Lightness I've been in situations where the user doesn't understand the language but once they click on the edit link in the comment they understand the idea. "Oh they want me to put that information in there". Remember that a great many forums do not allow you to edit your posts, and our edit link is pretty small.

Comment: @TinyGiant: Meh, arguably still no excuse for not looking up what the text means on those links. Certainly nothing's stopping them. People only seem to want to gain knowledge when they know what it is they need to gain knowledge about, which is sad.

Comment: @Lightness When I have an objective in mind, I really don't care about what a user can understand or not, I only care about getting them to do the thing with the least amount of input from me so I can move on. If that means linkifying a four letter word to save a conversation, then I approve.

Comment: @TinyGiant: And I prefer to train them to be better netizens/programmers/people in the long run. The more you mollycoddle, the less likely they are to bother looking around for themselves going forwards. And then you'll just have to do it all over again, every time.

Comment: Well, if I have to do it every time anyway and method A is much less effort than method B, I'd go with method B @Lightness.

Comment: @TinyGiant: _"if I have to do it every time anyway"_ This is the part that I pray & hope (possibly over-optimistically so!) that isn't true

Comment: @Lightness I find that it is true more often than false.

Comment: @TinyGiant: I'm not sure it's fundamentally provable either way, when it's an "every time" statement.

Comment: @Lightness More often than not I end up having to either explain how to find the edit link, or provide the user with the edit link. So, instead of wasting time and energy explaining how to find it I just provide the user with the link. This saves time and means I have more time for other moderation activities.

Comment: @TinyGiant: If you explain how to find it, that person will have learnt how to find things, and you/me/others will not need to spend time doing so with that person in the future. No?

Comment: In a perfect world yes, but often times the effort expended is unnecessarily wasted when the user either doesn't come back, or still can't figure it out the next time around. @Lightness

Comment: Meh. Your approach seems to be a confusing mix of altruism and .. not altruism. Ah well.

Comment: I don't like the premise of this question. I do not believe that this _"Users are posting answers instead of editing their question because they can't find the `edit` link"_ is true. I think users who do that don't read at all (either in a hurry, lazy, or not proficient in English), so they'll just as likely ignore any way the "please edit your question instead" comment is phrased.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Sometime yeah, but really there's some people can't find the edit link. And if you don't give them a link then it's hard for them to find it unless you say something like *the edit link is under the tags*...maybe still some people can't find it.

Comment: In other words: _I_ think this question tries to solve a problem that is either not there (honestly, how often does it happen?) and one that should not be solved.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Ah, I wouldn't call it a problem, but in other words: *I* think a magic link is *friendly*.

Comment: Maybe we could change the styling of the edit link to be more like a button? I can see why share and flag are not emphasized; most people won't do either. But editing seems like a key aspect of this site, and we want to encourage people to edit their questions when we put them on hold...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: Sounds good, but what about the other links? BTW, high rep users also can see **close** and **delete** link.